# Macbook Air Reboot after Wake when Windows 7 Running in VM

Tags: virtualbox, parallels, vmware-fusion, macbook-air

Is anyone who is running a Windows 7 VM on a new 2011 i5 Macbook Air (I have the 13" w/128 SSD) able to put their Macbook air to sleep for extended periods of time (like overnight) without manually shutting down or suspending a VM that's running in Parallels, VMware Fusion or VirtualBox?

I've tried all three virtualization products with no success.  With all three, if I forget to manually shutdown or suspend the VM, OSX reboots when I try and wake the Macbook.  Same goes if I try and use the Deep Sleep widget.  Parallels support openly admitted that this was an issue and thankfully gave me a refund.  I've also tried the trial version of VMware and VirtualBox, but the behavior is the same.

Should I just give up or is anyone out there having more success at this?

Answer (score 0):

fyi i can confirm the problem in VMWare.

I also have the 2011 13" Macbook air i7, and i'm running Lion 10.7.3 with VMWare Fusion 4.1.1 (purchased/full version). Inside the VM i am running Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 64bit.

Clicking the deep sleep widget for me also results in a crashed VM... (starting it up again Windows asks for safe mode startup).